# Passar duas variáveis concatenadas em um objeto Json de um POST Curl em PHP

Tags: php, json, api, post, libcurl

Estou enviando essa requisição json no  POST  do Curl com PHP.

Aqui o json do POST:

```
"Payment" => [
    "Type" => "Vendor",
    "Amount" => 100,
    "CreditCard" => [
    "CardNumber" =>  "$card",
    "ExpirationDate" =>   "$dataexp"     


    ]
```

O padrão para recebimento na api do ExpirationDate é : 20/2021  XX/XXXX  .

Dentro do "ExperationDate" => "",eu quero concatenar as duas variáveis ($mes e $ano) com o / (barra). $mes+/+$ano  ou essa logica em uma única variável.
Quando eu enviar o conteúdo do ExpirationDate deve ser 12/2021  XX/XXXX.

Eles vem de outras variáveis no script.$mes e $ano.

Retorna esse padrão enviando no ExperationData para a api no post.

Tentei algo como:

```
"ExperationDate" => "'.$mes.'/'.$ano.'"

"ExperationDate" => "$mes/$ano.'"

"ExperationDate" => "$mes./.$ano.'"
```

Em nenhumas das 3 possibilidades consegui.O $mes e $ano não concatenaram com o /.Assim o padrão ex: 10/2021 não foi passado corretamente no POST do objeto no json ExperationDate => ""

Tenho erro no ExperationDate  na api,o erro está exatamente no ponto de passagem de duas variáveis mais a / concatenada no ExperationDate.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a fazer nesse padrão que mostrei?
Seria possível passar duas variáveis e concatenadas dentro de um objeto json do post ?

Atenciosamente
Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver de maneira simples.Criei uma segunda variável que armazena o $mes / $ano e depois setei a variável no "ExpirationDate" =>   "$dataexp" .
Concatenando da seguinte forma:

```
$dataexp = $mes.'/'.$ano ;
```

Assim consegui resolver o problema enviando para a API o padrão de data correto XX/XXXX ex 12/2021.

Atenciosamente
Obrigado